# How to check if I have DDR3 or DDR3L

Tags: memory

On the sticker of my laptop and on the [website](http://www.emag.ro/laptop-acer-v5-552g-10578g50akk-cu-procesor-amd-quad-core-a10-5757m-2-50ghz-8gb-500gb-amd-radeontm-hd-8750m-2gb-linux-black-nx-mcuex-001/pd/D8D1JBBBM/) of the seller it says that I have DDR3 module. However running speccy and cpu-z it looked like the module is running at 1.35V also I removed the case and saw "PC3L" on the module's description, is it DDR3L? If useful here is the part number: HMT451S6MFR8A-PB

Comment: It should be clearly marked on the memory you already have.  English specifications are a must if you want help.  1.35V indicates low voltage memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DDR3L can run on both 1.35 V and 1.5 V, while DDR3 runs only on 1.5 V.

If CPU-Z reports that memory runs on 1.35 V, that means that you have DDR3L memory.
Also, PC3L is synonym for DDR3L.

If you are planing to upgrade your memory, buy DDR3L stick.

If you are planing to use existing stick in another laptop, do it without worrying, it can operate on 1.5 V too.

Comment: I want to move that module on a new laptop with Intel's Skylake arhitecture and that's why I was worrying so much.

Comment: Isnt Skylake DDR4 not DDR3?  If this new platform isn't a laptop it won't work either

Comment: @ramhound Quick google search revealed that Skylake supports both DDR3L and DDR4 (of course, depending on motherboard).

Dan, are you sure that your particular Skylake laptop uses DDR3L, not DDR4 memory?